# How to get user input from an output object

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a shiny app that dynamically creates a set of input boxes, the input from those boxes is then used to further create another set of input boxes.

First I get input from the "number of questions" text box and dynamically add that number of "question panels" to the ui (example below).
[image]

**Issue**

The issue is that the generated objects are always attached to the output, and I can't figure out how to grab new user input from them. How could I get this input, and then generate a second round of "answer" input boxes?

## ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("RSurvey"),
  numericInput("questionCountText", label = h3("Number of Questions"), value = 1),
  uiOutput("questionSet")
))
```

## server.R

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {    
      output[['questionSet']] <- renderUI({    
        
          outputHtml = ""
          count = input$questionCountText
          if(count > 0) {
            for(i in 1:input$questionCountText) {
              outputHtml = paste0(outputHtml, questionPanel(i))
            }
          }
          HTML(outputHtml)
      })        
  }
)

questionPanel = function(i)
{
  return(wellPanel(div(style="display:inline-block", textInput("questionText", label = h4(paste0("Question ", i)), "Enter your question")),
                                  numericInput1("answerCountText", label = h4("Number of Answers"), value = 3, onchange="onTextChanged(this.value)")))

}

numericInput1 = function (inputId, label, value = "", ...) 
{
  div(style="display:inline-block",
      tags$label(label, `for` = inputId), 
      tags$input(id = inputId, type = "numeric", value = value, ...))
}
```

Comment: You cannot use id  `questionText` several times, you have to do something like this : `paste0("questionText", i)` for start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello try this for example :

#### #ui

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("RSurvey"),
  numericInput("questionCountText", label = h3("Number of Questions"), value = 1),
  uiOutput("questionSet"),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "answers")
)
```

#### #server

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output[['questionSet']] <- renderUI({    

    outputHtml = ""
    count = input$questionCountText
    if(count > 0) {
      for(i in 1:input$questionCountText) {
        outputHtml = paste0(outputHtml, questionPanel(i))
      }
    }
    HTML(outputHtml)
  })

  output$answers <- renderPrint({
    invisible(
      sapply(
        X = seq_len(input$questionCountText),
        FUN = function(i) {
          cat(paste0("Question", i, "\n", input[[paste0("questionText", i)]], "\n", input[[paste0("answerCountText", i)]], "\n"))
        }
      )
    )
  })
}
```

#### #app

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### #utils

```
questionPanel = function(i) {
  wellPanel(
    div(
      style="display:inline-block",
      textInput2(inputId = paste0("questionText", i), label = h4(paste0("Question ", i)), placeholder = "Enter your question")
    ),
    numericInput1(inputId = paste0("answerCountText", i), label = h4("Number of Answers"), value = 3, onchange="onTextChanged(this.value)")
  )

}

numericInput1 = function (inputId, label, value = "", ...) {
  div(style="display:inline-block", class = "form-group shiny-input-container",
      tags$label(label, `for` = inputId), 
      tags$input(id = inputId, type = "number", value = value, ...))
}
`%AND%` <- shiny:::`%AND%`
textInput2 <- function (inputId, label, value = "", placeholder = NULL, width = NULL)
{
  if (is.null(placeholder)) {
    div(class = "form-group shiny-input-container", style = if (!is.null(width)) 
      paste0("width: ", validateCssUnit(width), ";"), label %AND% 
        tags$label(label, `for` = inputId), tags$input(id = inputId, 
                                                       type = "text", class = "form-control", value = value))
  } else {
    div(class = "form-group shiny-input-container", style = if (!is.null(width)) 
      paste0("width: ", validateCssUnit(width), ";"), label %AND% 
        tags$label(label, `for` = inputId), tags$input(id = inputId, placeholder = placeholder,
                                                       type = "text", class = "form-control", value = value))
  }
```

Comment: Thank you I got it working, but I'm not sure I understand whats happening.  Does the output object become part of the input? And that is why we can say myVar = input[[ ... ]] where "..." is an object that was created in the output?